# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (97,2048) into shape (97) when I try to execute fit_generator()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to replicate the code from this[1](https://github.com/hlamba28/Automatic-Image-Captioning/blob/master/Automatic%20Image%20Captioning.ipynb).It uses flickr 8k dataset and each image has 5 caption but here I'm using 3 instead of 5.

My caption_model is this:[image].Better representation is [image]

The objects I'm using are:

1. training_captions: It is a dict with 8k+ keys and each key has a list of 3 captions.
2. images: It is also a dict with 8k+ keys and each key is mapped to an array having shape (2048,)
3. vocab_size: It is size of a list of unique words having count more than a threshold in this case it is 10.So length of list is 2035 in this case.
4. wordtoix: where each word is mapped to an integer.
5. max_length:Max length of caption.In this case it is 74 and using this we pad each caption to this length.

Now I use this to create a generator which is

```
def data_generator(descriptions, photos, wordtoix, max_length, num_photos_per_batch):
    X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
    n=0
    # loop for ever over images
    while 1:
        for key, desc_list in descriptions.items():
            n+=1
            # retrieve the photo feature
            photo = photos[key]
            for desc in desc_list:
                # encode the sequence
                seq = [wordtoix[word] for word in desc.split(' ') if word in wordtoix]
                # split one sequence into multiple X, y pairs
                for i in range(1, len(seq)):
                    # split into input and output pair
                    in_seq, out_seq = seq[:i], seq[i]
                    # pad input sequence
                    in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq], maxlen=max_length)[0]
                    # encode output sequence
                    out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=vocab_size)[0]
                    # store
                    X1.append(photo)
                    X2.append(in_seq)
                    y.append(out_seq)
            # yield the batch data
            if n==num_photos_per_batch:
                print(array([[array(X1), array(X2)], array(y)]).shape)
                yield [[array(X1), array(X2)], array(y)]
                X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
                n=0
```

- List item

When I try to do

```
    for i in tqdm(range(EPOCHS*2)):
        generator= data_generator(training_captions, images, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
        caption_model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
```

I get the error

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-65d390168298> in <module>
      1 for i in tqdm(range(EPOCHS*2)):
      2     generator= data_generator(training_captions, images, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
----> 3     caption_model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)    

> c:\users\sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1294         shuffle=shuffle,
   1295         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1296         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1297 
   1298   def evaluate_generator(self,

> c:\users\sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    263 
    264       is_deferred = not model._is_compiled
--> 265       batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
    266       if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    267         batch_outs = [batch_outs]  


> c:\users\sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    989     x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_user_data(
    990         x, y, sample_weight=sample_weight, class_weight=class_weight,
--> 991         extract_tensors_from_dataset=True)
    992 
    993     # If `self._distribution_strategy` is True, then we are in a replica context

> c:\users\sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2469           feed_input_shapes,
   2470           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
-> 2471           exception_prefix='input')
   2472 
   2473     # Get typespecs for the input data and sanitize it if necessary.


> c:\users\sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    502   elif isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
    503     if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 504       data = [np.asarray(d) for d in data]
    505     elif len(names) == 1 and isinstance(data[0], (float, int)):
    506       data = [np.asarray(data)]
> 
> c:\users\sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    502   elif isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
    503     if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 504       data = [np.asarray(d) for d in data]
    505     elif len(names) == 1 and isinstance(data[0], (float, int)):
    506       data = [np.asarray(data)]
> 
> c:\users\sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (97,2048) into shape (97)

(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
```

I'm still learning so I'm unable to figure out what the problem is what I feel is that when I do yield in generator function it is returning the data in a shape which the model is not accepting but i don't know how to solve it or what changes to make.

Comment: What is the shape of the data yielded by your generator? And what is the shape of the data expected by your model?

Comment: Where do you have arrays with shape (97,2048)?   `images`?  I suspect you a list of arrays like that, but which differ somewhat in shape.

Comment: @GPhilo when I do next(generator) and find the shape I get:Total items in data:  2
Encodded Y shape:  (138, 2035)
Example Y:  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
X1 shape (image feature):  (138, 2048)
X2 shape (image caption):  (138, 74)

Comment: @hpaulj yah I don't have an array with the shape (97,2048) I do have image feature array which has a shape (138,2048) .i don't know where that 97 is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I asked about arrays with shape like  (97,2048) is that the error message is that kind that appears in a construction like:

```
In [109]: np.asarray([np.ones((3,4)),np.zeros((3,2))])                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-3d43433206a6> in <module>
----> 1 np.asarray([np.ones((3,4)),np.zeros((3,2))])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,4) into shape (3)
```

This tries to combine (3,4) and (3,2) shaped arrays into one.  Note the matching first dimension.  If the first dimensions differed the result would be an object dtype array, an array of arrays.  If the all dimensions were the same the result would be a (2,3,4) array.

But since the error occurs deep in a tensorflow stack of calls it is hard to trace the problem back up to your own code.  But as far as I can tell that's the only clue we have.

In this error, the 2nd dimension differs.  So if you have a list of arrays, with shape (n,2048), but where one or two are (n,2035) you could get this error.  I'd check carefully the size of the images.